# Display a sharepoint list row in a table with JS

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-list, display-templates

I have a sharpoint list with one row containing project info.
projectnumber
ProjectName
ProjectAdmin
Contracter
and so on. I want to display this as a nice table in the teamsite.
I reckon this is done with a display template or Javascript. I tryed this code, but it returns undefined for the custom fields
Please help..

```
(function () {

var itemCtx = {};
itemCtx.Templates = {};

    itemCtx.Templates.Header = "<div><b></b></div><table>";
    itemCtx.Templates.Item = ItemOverrideFun;
    itemCtx.Templates.Footer = "</table>";

itemCtx.ListTemplateType = 100;

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(itemCtx);

})();


function ItemOverrideFun(ctx) {

var var_prnummer = ctx.CurrentItem.Prosjektnummer;
var var_prnavn = ctx.CurrentItem.Prosjektnavn;
var var_prleder = ctx.CurrentItem.Prosjektleder;
var var_endret = ctx.CurrentItem.Endret


return "<tr style='background-color: #AEE33B;width: 300px;height: 24px;'><td>Prosjektnummer</td><td>" 

+ var_prnummer + "</td></tr>"
+ "<tr><td>Prosjektnavn</td><td>" + var_prnavn + "</td></tr>"
+ "<tr><td>Prosjektleder</td><td>" + var_prleder + "</td></tr>"
+ "<tr><td>Endret</td><td>" + var_endret + "</td></tr>"

"</span>";

}
```

screenshot.
https://1drv.ms/i/s!Ao_2YX-U1uKUlsxL93IYeHEgIV5ZfA

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the javascript object model JSOM. This is what you need:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163201.aspx#BasicOps_SPListItemTasks